MongoDB binary subtype
I have my class containing a byte[] field then I am using this class as my model for the mongo collection, I know that the field in mongo will end up as Binary, which is fine, but what I need is to also change the subtype
So, I know that I can use BsonBinaryData for my field but my project shoudn't have anything related to mongo so it needs to be byte[] or even string and I should find a way to map the class in a way that in my db the subtype will be whatever i need(6 in my case)
m.MapMember(mi => mi.MyByteArrayField)
.SetSerializer(new ByteArraySerializer(BsonBinarySubType.Encrypted));
I tried something like this but the serializer does't have a serializer for this kind of input

You can create a custom serializer that inherits from SerializerBase<byte[]> and overrides the Serialize method to set the subtype.
public class CustomByteArraySerializer : SerializerBase<byte[]>
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, byte[] value)
    {
        var binaryData = new BsonBinaryData(value, BsonBinarySubType.UserDefined);
        BsonSerializer.Serialize(context.Writer, binaryData);
    }
}

Then, you can use this custom serializer in your class map:
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapMember(c => c.MyByteArrayField).SetSerializer(new CustomByteArraySerializer());
});

